Stationary waves do not transfer energy
My A-level physics textbook states: "Stationary waves that vibrate freely do not transfer energy to their surroundings". I do not understand this statement.
How can it not transfer energy to the surroundings? Does it not push particles in the air away when it vibrates? How can it not transfer energy to the surroundings?
If the statement had said : Stationary waves do not transmit energy along the wave. That makes sense to me as stationary waves have a node at each end and so would not transfer energy from one end to the other.
Please help me understand this statement.
Also, what does the textbook mean by "freely vibrating"?

Does this answer your question? Stationary waves and transfer of energy
